# Can we know the equation of line " $L$ " from one point $P(a,b)$ in this line?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, curves

Suppose we have a point $ p(a,b)$ a and b are given and let $L$ be a line s.t $p(a,b) $ belong to $L$
By this information can we know the equation of L in terms of $P(a.b)$ ?can it gives as more information about $ L$?

Comment: please type the question using latex e.g., use dollar symbol ($) before and after any math expression. Also  show your first effort toward the answer. You have to write what you have tried

Comment: Ok thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

If we just have one point $p(a,b)$ known then there are $\text{infinitely (uncountably) many }$ straight lines passing through it. We have to know at least two points to identify the equation of a line. See Euclid's first postulate [here](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ectm/home/text/class/harvard/113/97/html/euclid.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry)

Answer (score 0):

"Suppose we have a point p(a,b) a and b are given and let L be a line s.t p(a,b) belong to L By this information can we know the equation of L in terms of P(a.b) ?can it gives as more information about L?"
I'm not sure I understand this.  You say "p(a, b)" is a point but what are a and b?  Do you mean that p is a "point valued function of a and b"?  If a and b are independent variables, then p(a, b) will, in general, be two dimensional, a plane, not a line.